# Gaussian distributed random numbers in OpenCL

Tags: random, opencl, gaussian

I am running a computational expensive task on the GPU using OpenCL. This task requires many random numbers generated within each worker. Some of those random numbers are supposed to be uniformly generated within a certain interval, but some others have to be gaussian distributed around a (changing) value.

1. Is there any library for this?
2. If not, what's an easy way to implement such a thing?

So far I have been creating the random numbers in python and have them passed to OpenCL. However the bottleneck now is the transfer of those random numbers (at least an order of magnitude slower than the actual computations).

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912143/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-opencl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) is an easily parallelized method for transforming uniform random variates into normally distributed ones. I've used it in conjunction with the Random123 library that ddemidov mentioned.

Comment: Be careful using Box-Muller with linear congruential generators, there's a well-known interaction between the algorithms which causes the results to fall along a spiral.

Answer (score 1):

[VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl) library [provides](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl#random-number-generation) counter-based random number generators from [Random123](http://www.deshawresearch.com/resources_random123.html) suite (disclaimer: I am the developer of the library).

Also check [Boost.compute](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute) and [ViennaCL](http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/) libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The [Boost.Compute](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/index.html) library provides the [`normal_distribution`](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost/compute/normal_distribution.html) class along with several random-number generators ([`mersenne_twister_engine`](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost/compute/mersenne_twister_engine.html) and [`linear_congruential_engine`](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost/compute/linear_congruential_engine.html)). These can be used together to produce normally (aka gaussian) distributed random values on the device.

For example, to produce random `float` values centered at `5.0`:

```
// create a vector of floats on the device
boost::compute::vector<float> vec(1000, context);

// initialize the default random engine
boost::compute::default_random_engine engine(queue);

// setup the normal distribution to produce floats centered at 5
boost::compute::normal_distribution<float> distribution(5.0f, 1.0f);

// generate the random values and store them to 'vec'
distribution.generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), engine, queue);
```