# Get an Random Number within Range in OpenCL

Tags: c++, random, range, opencl

How do I get an Random Number within a specific range in OpenCL?

E.G. Random Numbers between 1 and 100. :)

Would be great if it could be made easy.
It must be OpenCL specific I think.
The Generation must be done in the Kernel.

Comment: i cant use rand() in opencl kernel!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a "random" number in OpenCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912143/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-opencl)

Comment: no it needs to be in a specific range !

Comment: i heard something about reminding and multiplication.

Comment: ok multiplication, nice idea